# Laravel middleware not working

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3, middleware

I have a middleware class :-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;


use Closure;

class isAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(auth()->user()->getIsAdminAttribute()){

            return $next($request);


        }
        abort(404);
    }
}
```

In Kernel.php file:-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use App\Http\Middleware\isAdmin;

protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'isAdmin' => isAdmin::class,
    ];
```

In web.php route file:-

```
Route::get('users/list', 'UsersController@listUsers')->name('List_Users')->middleware('isAdmin');
```

I've tried to dump the

```
dd(auth()->user()->getIsAdminAttribute());
```

Nothing happen , like I am not assigning isAdmin middleware to that route at all.

Comment: First of all, I think you should check this [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators). In your example, you use getIsAdminAttribute method of User Model, but in this case it shoud be used as     is_admin method.

auth()->user()->is_admin.

So check it first.

Comment: @Pavel Thanks for your reply , You are totally right with this , but even if I want to change my code , I wont be able to check if it work or not because as I mentioned , I tried in middleware class to dd(auth()->user()->getIsAdminAttribute()); or type any thing wrong , no error showing with me . If middleware is really work and it filer the request , at least it should show error

Comment: try `dd(auth()->user())`

Comment: @Sohel0415 , even that , I cannot figure out if there is wrong with my middleware syntax , if middleware is totally not working , my situation is assigning middleware to that route is not effecting request to that route )->middleware('isAdmin');  , like I did not assign any middleware to that route.

Comment: try with fully qualified class `Route::get('users/list', 'UsersController@listUsers')->name('List_Users')->middleware(isAdmin::class)`

Comment: @Sohel0415 , tried nothing changed.

Comment: have you cleared cache, route, config??

Comment: @Sohel0415, I tried before and now , php artisan view:clear , route:cache , cache:clear , nothing happened.

Comment: that's weird, let us know if you can solve this

Comment: @Sohel0415 , yes very weird , sure I will , thanks for trying.

Comment: And what's about trying `dd()` function inside middleware class in `Handle` method. This will help you to see is your middleware really assigned to route. Then the only advice to check your `getIsAdminAttribute` method.

Comment: @Pavel Tried , with dd('this is test'); not doing anything

Answer (score 1):

You could check your routes and middleware assigned to them with this command :

```
php artisan route:list
```

Should look like :

```
+--------+----------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI         | Name       | Action                                          | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /           |            | Closure                                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | users/list  | List_Users | App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@listUsers  | web,isAdmin  |
+--------+----------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Note the isAdmin in the middleware column.

Answer (score -1):

i know it's late for you but maybe someone else will benefit from it,
i had the same issue, and after some debugging i found that the problem the middlware wasn't fired and appear in route:list due to the Route::get('post/{id}') even if i put this route after the route who was facing the issue Route::get('post/create'), i changed the show route from post to posts and the middleware get fired again.